# How to change the directory of avro schema file on sqoop free form query import?

Tags: sqoop

Inspite of me mentioning --target-dir the 'QueryResult.avsc' file gets created in the current working directory instead of target directory.

Answer (score 1):

The --target-dir gives the location of data, --outdir will give you the avro schema file local location

```
sqoop import  --connect '$JDBC_URL;databaseName=$DBNAME;username=$USERNAME;password=$PASSWORD' --query 'select * from $tableName where $CONDITIONS' --outdir $AVRO_SCHEMA_COLLECTOR_LOCAL  --target-dir $AVRO_SQOOPDATA_COLLECTOR --fields-terminated-by '\001' --split-by $splitKey -m 8 --as-avrodatafile
```

Comment: Hi Vinayak, if we use 'select query ' in sqoop the avaro schema file is storing the table name as 'QueryResult'...how do we make it as tablename...please help on this.

Comment: in that case you have to use --table instead of  --query . But if your requirement is that of using --query you have to rename your QueryResult.avsc to tableName.avsc in shell script. Hope this helps